# How to Redirect Multiple Domain Names to a Main site in GAE

Tags: domains, redirects, 301-redirect, google-app-engine

I am using google app engine to run a website and I have a website that I would like to be my main page and I have a few other domains that I want to redirect to the main page.  The purpose of this is for common misspellings.

I am not sure how to do this because it doesn't give you the option to set up a redirect only to choose which websites will host the actual site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not connected all your domains to your GAE app. in that case you can use redirecting options offered by your domain host.

GAE is just like any other web hosting, if you have connected each of your domains to an app, you can use a simple HTTP redirect, preferably a *["301 moved permanently"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)*, to do this, you need to have an HTML index/landing page uploaded to your app.